# Нужна помощь со вставкой данных из html таблицы в mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Создал корзину для сайта, по логике все названия товаров из которой должны вставляться в базу данных mysql(в один столбец через запятую), но вставляется только последняя строчка.

То есть проблема не в том, что в базу данных вообще ничего не идёт, а в том что в нее записывается только последняя строчка из корзины(в конкретном случае торт "изумительный пломбир").

Вот мой код:

```
<?php

    session_start();
    require_once 'connect.php';

    $user_name = $_SESSION['user']['full_name'];
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $equal = $_POST['equal'];
    $totalprice = $_POST['totalprice'];
    $tel = $_POST['tel'];
    $adress = $_POST['adress'];

    mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO `orders` (`id`, `user_name`, `title`, `equal`, `total_price`, `tel`, `adress`, `status`) VALUES (NULL, '$user_name', '$title', '$equal', '$totalprice', '$tel', '$adress', 'Ожидается подтверждение')");

    header('Location: ../profile.php');

?>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Код полностью верен, что вы отправляете/получаете, то и сохраняете. А сохраняете вы общие данные заказа, но вот списка товаров в корзине я не вижу

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

session_start();
require_once 'connect.php';

$user_name = $_SESSION['user']['full_name'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
$adress = $_POST['adress'];

// Получаем массив с товарами из сессии
$cart = $_SESSION['cart'];

// Перебираем каждый товар в корзине и вставляем его в базу данных
foreach ($cart as $item) {
    $title = $item['title'];
    $equal = $item['equal'];
    $totalprice = $item['totalprice'];

    mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO `orders` (`id`, `user_name`, `title`, `equal`, `total_price`, `tel`, `adress`, `status`) VALUES (NULL, '$user_name', '$title', '$equal', '$totalprice', '$tel', '$adress', 'Ожидается подтверждение')");
}

// Очищаем корзину
$_SESSION['cart'] = array();

header('Location: ../profile.php');
?>
```

Comment: Это же на каждый товар будет запрос на вставку. Можно сформировать строку в цикле, дописать запрос после `VALUES` где данные через запятую будут `(), ()`, а вставку вне цикла сделать.